# Cannot access the proxy of a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I created a kubernetes cluster on my debian 9 machine using [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/).
Which apparently works because I can run `kubectl cluster-info` with valid output.

Now I wanted to fool around with the tutorial on [Learn Kubernetes Basics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/#kubernetes-basics-modules) site.

I have already deployed the app

```
kubectl create deployment kubernetes-bootcamp --image=gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1
```

and started the `kubectl proxy`.

Output of `kubectl get deployments`

```
NAME                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubernetes-bootcamp   1/1     1            1           17m
```

My problem now is: when I try to see the output of the application using `curl` I get

> Error trying to reach service: 'dial tcp 10.244.0.5:80: connect: connection refused'

My commands

```
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}')
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME/proxy/
```

For the sake of completeness I can run `curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME/` and I get valid output.

Comment: Provide your service file please

Comment: I do not have a service file, I just run the `kubectl create deployment ...` command as shown above. I followed the steps from this [module](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/deploy-app/deploy-interactive/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps from this tutorial module represent environment as if You were working on one of the cluster nodes.

And the command tries to check connectivity to service locally on the node.

However In Your case by running Your kubernetes in a docker (kind) cluster the curl command is most likely ran from the host that is serving the docker containers that have kubernetes in it.

It might be possible to use [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to get inside kind node and try to run curl command from there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Try add :8080 after the **$POD_NAME**

```
 curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME:8080/proxy/
```

Comment: This works, and I'd be delighted to know why.

Comment: @weeix This works because the pod name is replaced with the IP address. By default it will try <ip>:80, but by specifying port to :8080 it internally resolves to <ip>:8080.

Comment: @weeix, to complete James's answer, the port 8080 is the port on which the service inside the docker gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1 is listening.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also doing following the tutorial using kind and got it to work forwarding the port:

```
 kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8001:8001
```